# Collation difference between official and Oracle Docker images of MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, docker

We have a development environment that spins up using `mysql:8.0.18` from the Docker library. This image doesn't provide multi-arch (read: arm64) builds, so we'd like to switch to `mysql/mysql-server:8.0.18` instead.

However - we're consistently encountering an issue during our app container startup (when running migrations) when using `mysql/mysql-server` **only**:

```
ERROR: Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Taking a look at the character/collation variables of the failing server:

```
mysql> show variables like "%collat%";
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value              |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection          | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_database            | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_server              | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| default_collation_for_utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show variables like "%character%";
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                         |
| character_set_connection | latin1                         |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | latin1                         |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

We have a small `my.cnf` which gets dropped into both images:

```
[mysqld]
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=ON
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
character_set_server=utf8     # removing this line has no effect on this issue
```

I have two primary questions:

1. What's the root difference between the official Docker image for MySQL 8.0.18 and the Oracle-provided copy, and
2. How can we configure our `mysql/mysql-server` container to behave more like `mysql`?

**Links:**

Official image: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Oracle image: https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

Comment: The error message tells that you try to compare the value of the column and string literal. utf8mb4_unicode_ci is not listed in settings - this means that it was set to the column or table or database row during creation. You may alter table. You may alter connection collation. You may specify the collation in query text.

Comment: Thanks @Akina, why would we choose to alter the table or query text, when a different build of MySQL 8.0.18 handles it fine - is this potentially a system/environment setting we can change in the Docker container itself?

Note this is reproducible: Starting with fresh+empty `mysql` and `mysql/mysql-server` containers, the migration succeeds on one, and fails on the other.

Comment: I do not use docker so I cannot say something about its predefined installations. Try to compare their settings lists (export SHOW VARIABLES and compare row-by-row), search for differences which may cause your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our custom `my.cnf` was not being read. We were placing it at:

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
```

Which works for the official `mysql` image, but in the `mysql/mysql-server` variant, it should be placed at:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```